# Python Selenium advancing through website's second page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working with this website: https://www.offerte.smartpaws.de/

Using selenium, I scraped through the first page, and did a click to go to the next section with very simple buttons, however, after continuing to the second page I get a timout exception while trying to click on the first button (gender).

Below is the code I used for going to the next page:

```
#click button to go to next page
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="button_get_quote"]'))).click()
            time.sleep(2)
           #loop though genders
            for gender in ["male","female"]:
                if gender == "male":
#click on male button
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dog_form_s"]/div/div[1]/div/div/input[1]'))).click()
                else:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dog_form_g"]/div/div[1]/div/div/input[2]'))).click()
```

I have tried using `try:`in case it was just taking long and added a `time.sleep()` for the same reason, but still get a timeout error.

Do you guys know of any tricks to fix this or perhaps why it is happening, I thought it might be that I have to redifine the `drive.get()` to the new page, but nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see elements matching `//*[@id="dog_form_s"]/div/div[1]/div/div/input[1]` locator on the second page there.
The same about `//*[@id="dog_form_g"]/div/div[1]/div/div/input[2]` XPath.
In order to select Male pet gender you can use this XPath: `//input[@value='male ']`
and correspondingly `//input[@value='female']` to select Female pet gender.

Comment: I copied directly the Xpath from the elements.

Comment: The automatically generated locators from the dev tools? They are very fragile and not reliable.

Comment: Please let me know if my locators worked for you

Comment: Same error while using `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="yes_no_widget btn-outline"]/input[@value="Männlich"]'))).click()` Not sure if I used it correctly there

Comment: This is not what I have suggested here...

Comment: what should I change? How can I click on it, the method in my code worked for the previous page, only when going to the next page it does not find it.

Comment: I think  can explain that. But can you tell me: have you tried my solution? Did it work?

Comment: I tried, it did not work, same timeout error

Comment: OK, please try this XPath for male: `//input[@name='id_form-0-gender' and @rel='M']` and this for female `//input[@name='id_form-0-gender' and @rel='F']` let me know if that worked.

Comment: that worked, I guess I will apply that structure everywhere, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. So `//input[@value='male ']` possibly not worked since `male` is a language dependable value while `name` and `rel` attribute values are fixed